# When job1 is built how to automatically trigger the 2nd job to enter parameters manually without passing the parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I am new to jenkins. I have a job named job1 where it gets successfully build (with parameters). I want to automatically trigger my second job creation but not pass parameters. I want to go to the screen of build with  parameters of second job and enter the parameters for the second job manually right after the job1 is built.
I have looked for a solution on the whole Internet but all the automatic trigger examples do not let me to enter the parameters for the second job manually.
How can I implement this?

Comment: Not quite sure i understand, but you just want to manually run a job after another one has finished? if so when the first job finishes notify yourself (mail, slack) with the link to the other job and execute it.

Comment: After the first job is built, is there any chance to automatically redirect to the 2nd jobs build with parameters stage?

Comment: In my scenario what i am doing is I have this python script which return some values. In my second job those values will be displayed as an option to select as parameters. Is there any chance to perform in a chain? Like after the first built can we redirect to the 2nd job parameters page?

Comment: What do you mean by redirect? Redirect who?

Comment: I directly go to the build stage of job 2 (Build with parameters) after job 1 is build? I want to automatically go that stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found an solution this. Jenkins pipeline project is the answer! You can input any parameter you want at any stage with an input message.